# which log level is the output by the statement "log.debug" print in tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat

according to the documentation:https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html
in tomcat 8 ,the log levels are:
SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL.

which log level is the statement's output ? DEBUG=FINE?

log.debug(sm.getString("webappClassLoader.resourceModified",
                            entry.getKey(),
                            new Date(cachedLastModified),
                            new Date(lastModified)));

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase

```java
public boolean modified() {

        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("modified()");

        for (Entry<String,ResourceEntry> entry : resourceEntries.entrySet()) {
            long cachedLastModified = entry.getValue().lastModified;
            long lastModified = resources.getClassLoaderResource(
                    entry.getKey()).getLastModified();
            if (lastModified != cachedLastModified) {
                if( log.isDebugEnabled() )
                    log.debug(sm.getString("webappClassLoader.resourceModified",
                            entry.getKey(),
                            new Date(cachedLastModified),
                            new Date(lastModified)));
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: First: In the worst case you had log2(8) attempts to find that by trial and error and would have been much faster for you than writing this question. Second: Most probably its `FINE`, but no one can tell you with certainty, because you have not told us which logging framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. the logging framework is: java.util.logging

Comment: No it's not - java.util.logging does not have `debug` level.

Comment: what is the default logging framework used in tomcat 8 ? Is not 'java.util.logging'?

Comment: Yes, its. But as you can see, there is no `debug()` method there, as in your example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Comment: you are right.the 'log' in the 'log.debug' is a instance of 'org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog',not 'java.util.logging.Logger'

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good question,i should find the answer by trial and error.

```java
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                log.debug("Checking context[" + app.name +
                        "] redeploy resource " + resource);
```

the log is :
12-Jun-2019 11:05:21.833 FINE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources Checking context[/test-web] redeploy resource /opt/tomcat/webapps/test-web.war

so the conclusion is :DEBUG= FINE

org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog

```java
@Override
    public final boolean isDebugEnabled() {
        return logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE);
    }
```